# convertSendAndReceive is not working when the queue is Shoveled

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

FYI, I'm a newbie with RabbitMQ.

I have this use case for my application for which I'm trying to use RabbitMQ:

- Producer sends some message to the queue
- Consumer process and send a reply
- Based on the reply Producer acts on

For the above scenario, I used convertSendAndReceive which works like a charm when both producer and consumer are in same RabbitMQ server. But the same does not work when the queue is Shoveled.

Please let me know if I using the wrong method/configuration w.r.t RabbitMQ.

Thanks in advance.

Adding Code

Consumer

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       ConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory("10.223.19.89");        

        // set up the queue, exchange, binding on the broker
        RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(cf);
        Queue queue = new Queue("myQueue");
        Queue queueReply = new Queue("myQueue_reply");

        admin.declareQueue(queue);
        admin.declareQueue(queueReply);
        TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange("myExchange");

        admin.declareExchange(exchange);
        admin.declareBinding(
            BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("foo.*"));
        admin.declareBinding(
                BindingBuilder.bind(queueReply).to(exchange).with("foo.*"));

        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container =
                new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        Object listener = new Object() {
            public String handleMessage(String foo) {            
                return foo + "test";
            }
        };

        MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(listener);

        container.setMessageListener(adapter);          
        container.setQueueNames("myQueue");         
        container.start();

}
```

---

Producer

```
public void run()
{  

    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    ConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory("10.223.19.93");

    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cf);
    template.setExchange("myExchange");
    template.setRoutingKey("foo.bar");
    Queue queueReply = new Queue("myQueue_reply");
    template.setReplyQueue(queueReply);     

    Object test = template.convertSendAndReceive("Hello world");
    System.out.println(test.toString());

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new SendReceiveThread());
        t.setName("Thread # " + i);
        t.start();      
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }

}
```

Comment: Also note that I have configured fwd headers in Shovel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is you need to use a [named reply queue](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply) and shovel it as well.

You will need a `<reply-listener/>` for this scenario.

Prior to rabbitmq 3.4, a temporary queue was used for the replies; direct reply-to is used with 3.4 and above, but my guess is that rabbit doesn't shovel the pseudo queue created for that.

**EDIT**:

When using a fixed reply queue and creating the rabbit template programmatically, you have to wire up a listener container and set the template as the listener. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e1084).

> If you define your RabbitTemplate as a `<bean/>`, or using an `@Configuration` class to define it as an `@Bean`, **or when creating the template programmatically**, you will need to define and wire up the reply listener container yourself. If you fail to do this, the template will never receive the replies and will eventually time out and return null as the reply to a call to a sendAndReceive method.

Comment: I used name reply queue and a shovel for the same and I could see the replies are in producer's  reply queue. But, I don't see convertSendAndReceive fetching the reply from that queue.

Comment: Show all your configuration.

Comment: Thanks that did worked. Got one more question, I could see the reply-listener runs even after reading from queue. is it possible to stop once the receive is completed?

Comment: There's nothing built-in; you could start/stop it before/after each request but that might be a bit too much overhead; you could schedule a `stop()` if no requests have been sent for so many seconds and re-`start()` on the next message. However, there's not much overhead in keeping the reply container running, so I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: Yet another issue I when I have a multiple instance of Producer then things get screw up. let me know if you want to put the codes in same thread or somewhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84475/discussion-between-vivek-dhayalan-and-gary-russell).

Answer (score 0):

In spring-rabbit-1.4, you just config the consumer like this:
{rabbit:template id="tutorialTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" exchange="TRUST-EXCHANGE" routing-key="my.#" }

The most important is that you must removed the "replyQueue" config element. In this case, you use the spring default "reply-to" which is in https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html.

Comment: <rabbit:template id="tutorialTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" exchange="TRUST-EXCHANGE" routing-key="my.#" />